# Is This Noun in the Dative or Ablative

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, ablative, dative

I was reading the last chapter of *Fabellae Latīnae*, "Puer Barbarus", when I came across this sentence:

> Dāvus: Laetāre quod tibi licet in lūdum īre – **mihi puerō** non licēbat.

And I understand that it means:

> Be glad that you are allowed (lit. is is allowed for you) to go to school. To me as a child, it was not.

But I was wondering what case *puerō* is in in that sentence:

- **Dative,** agreeing with *mihi*, literally meaning "to me-boy", or
- **Ablative** *of time* of some sort, meaning "during the time I was a boy", i.e. "during my boy-days / childhood".

However, I couldn't find any reference to such an ablative of time with a similar example sentence (i.e., a noun describing a person of a certain age in the ablative, to represent that time period in one's life).

**Perhaps I am overthinking this with the ablative interpretation**, and instead I should become more familiarized with the "personal pronoun + noun agreeing in case" compound expression? (mihi puerō)

There's an additional sentence using the same form further in the chapter:

> Multa **mihi puerō** erant officia, nec enim servum nec ancillam habēbat pater meus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puero is a dative in apposition to mihi. Appositives in Latin often have an adverbial component (cf. A&G [282](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/agreement-nouns)). Here it tells us when the statement applies.

This construction is perhaps most commonly seen with a nominative in apposition to the implied subject of a verb.

Audivi hoc de parente meo puer

I heard this from my father when I was a boy.

Cicero, Pro Balbo

Comment: Do you think that the _inner_ syntactic structure of _mihi puero_ is different from that of the so-called Ablative Absolute (AA) _me puero_? I'm raising this point since there is an interesting debate in the literature on Latin syntax as to whether the AA is an expanded Nominal Phrase (e.g. Ruppel 2013: p. 10, i.a.) or is a subordinate clause (e.g. Pinkster 2021: p. 5, i.a.).

Comment: @Mitomino I don't have the numbers on me, but aren't phrases like *me puero*, where the subject of the ablative absolute is the same as the subject of the sentence, relatively rare, especially compared to ones where the ablative absolute does not relate to the subject (e.g. *Caesare consule Cicero ad me scripsit*)?

Comment: @cmw Yes, examples with this subject coreferentiality are very rare in Classical Latin (e.g. _Coactis equitum milibus VIII...haec... recensebantur_ (Caes. _Gall_. VII, 76, 3); e.g. according to Tarriño (2000: 60), "La proporción en el libro <VII Bell. Gall.> de César es por tanto de 1/290, mientras que en G(regory of)T(ours) ha aumentado a 1/55": https://gredos.usal.es/bitstream/handle/10366/55584/978-84-7800-902-2.pdf?sequence=1). In contrast, it seems that this subject coreferentiality is frequent in inscriptions (e.g.  _/monumentum/me vivo aedific/avi_ . . .  CIL I.1251.3–5 (Rome, Rep.))).

Comment: @Mitomino That makes me thinks it's a matter of formality rather than grammar.

Comment: @cmw Formality/genre/style/... is indeed relevant (e.g. Classical Latin prose vs. inscriptions) but at the same time grammar (in this case, syntax and its connection with information structure) is also relevant when accounting for why the abovementioned example that involves subject coreferentiality is so infrequent compared to another examples that are also said to violate the typical AA rule (for more discussion, see https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/grammatical-structure-of-obsidibus-imperatis-centum-hos-haeduis-custodiendos-tr/15058#15058 ).

Comment: @Mitomino: How are you translating, "me puero" = "with me having been a boy"; rendered to, "when I was a boy"? Did the Romans say it like this?

Comment: @cmw: In "Caesare consule Cicero ad me scripsit" = "with Caesar having been Consul, Cicero wrote to me", is it rendered to "when Caesar was Consul..." or, "when Caesar was made Consul..."?

Comment: @tony The former. You would see a verb if it were the latter.

Comment: @tony Note that one thing is how we translate it into English (e.g. 'when I (was) a child') and a very different one is how we analyze the Latin expression. One should not mix _translation_ to his language with _analysis_ of the original language. I'm saying this because your "with me having been a boy" seems a mix of translation and analysis. I disagree with those who think that there is an elliptical participle in AA's like _me puero_ (cf. its presence in Ancient Greek). In my view, the constituent _Cicerone consule_ has the same analysis as _Ciceronem consulem_ in _post Ciceronem consulem_.